# Javascript function from a rendered shared view does not see objects/functions from the main view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a page with a grid and a filter. Filter is reused in several places, that is why it was decided to move it into separate view and include by using `Html.RenderAction`.

Everything works fine when page is completely loaded. However, I want to filter the grid on the event `$(document).ready` and here I get a problem - parent's view doesn't see objects and functions in the child view and vice versa.

Thus, when I try something like
this in the child view:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if(window.onFilterIsReady) {
            window.onFilterIsReady();
        }
    });
```

and in the main view:

```
function onFilterIsReady() {
    filter();
}
```

`onFilterIsReady` cannot be found.

Is it the way it supposed to work?

Edit: figure out the problem. The reason for the problem in the scenario above was that when $(document).ready for the child view is called, the parent view isn't loaded yet. Thus, function onFilterIsReady indeed doesn't exist.

When I call from parent to child - everything works fine. (Previously, I made an error in dynamically generated variables names and that is why I couldn't access it)

Comment: global objects usually are evil. use namespace.

Comment: I hope you haven't wrapped the `onFilterIsReady` function definition in your main view inside a `document.ready` callback?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, no, of course not. I tried, actually, to use document.ready in the main view to access dropdown from the child view - same story, couldn't find it.

Comment: Is the code inside the `document.ready` in your child view ever executed? What happens if you put an `alert` inside it just before the `if` condition?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, yes, it is executed, I can debug it. I see that window.onFilterIsReady doesn't exists.

Comment: Could you show the generated HTML markup as seen in the browser (view source ...)?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the main view" ? I suspect the scope in which you define your function is not really the global scope...